# I want to use pagination to my app. I have an API like this:

Tags: ios, swift, api

I want to use pagination to my app. I have an API like this: https://example.com/api/?action=persons_detailed&limit=5

I want to use in my collectionview 10 persons, then when scrolling update my request. The whole persons are 5200 people that's why I need pagination.

This is my api service in my project:

```
import Foundation

protocol ExampleService {
 typealias PersonCompletion = (PagedResult<Person>) -> Void
 func persons(page: Int, resultsPerPage: Int, completion: @escaping PersonCompletion)
}

class ExampleWebService: ExampleService {

 func persons(page: Int, resultsPerPage: Int, completion: @escaping (PagedResult<Person>) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/api/?action=persons_detailed&limit=\(resultsPerPage)")!
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }
        do {
            try validate(response)

            let persons: [Person] = try parse(data)
            let personPage = PagedResult(pageNumber: page, results: persons)
            completion(personPage)
            print(data)
        }
        catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
 }
}
```

And this is my collection View :

```
import UIKit

class PersonListViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var personPages: [PagedResult<Person>] = [] {
    didSet {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadPersons()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first else {
        return
    }
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: animated)
}

var service = ExampleWebService()
private func loadPersons(page: Int = 0, resultsPerPage: Int = 10) {
    service.persons(page: page, resultsPerPage: resultsPerPage) { (personPage) in
        guard !self.loadedPersonPageNumbers.contains(page) else { return }
        self.personPages.append(personPage)
        self.updateLastIndexPath(personPage)
    }
}

private(set) var lastIndexPath: IndexPath?
private func updateLastIndexPath(_ personPage: PagedResult<Person>) {
    if personPage.results.isEmpty {
        lastIndexPath = nil
    }
    else {
        lastIndexPath = calculateLastIndexPath()
    }
}

private func calculateLastIndexPath() -> IndexPath? {
    guard let lastPage = personPages.last else { return nil }
    let section = lastPage.pageNumber
    let row = lastPage.results.count - 1
    return IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
}

fileprivate var loadedPersonPageNumbers: [Int] {
    return personPages.map { $0.pageNumber }
}

func person(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Person? {
    guard indexPath.section < personPages.count else {
        return nil
    }
    guard indexPath.row < personPages[indexPath.section].results.count else {
        return nil
    }
    let page = personPages[indexPath.section]
    return page.results[indexPath.row]
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let personViewController = segue.destination as? PersonViewController,
        let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first else {
        return
    }
    personViewController.person = person(at: selectedIndexPath)
}

 @IBAction func exitToPersonsView(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

 }
}

extension PersonListViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
 fileprivate var nextPageIndex: Int {
    guard let lastPage = personPages.last else {
        return 0
    }

    return lastPage.pageNumber.advanced(by: 1)
 }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath == lastIndexPath {
        loadPersons(page: nextPageIndex)
    }
 }
}
```

The problem is that when I scrolling the CollectionView it brings me the same first 10 persons, instead of updating from 11 persons to 21 etc..

Comment: The API with these parameters doesn't really support pagination, because you can only set a limit. If you set the higher, you'll get the FIRST x number of people (starting with index 0 always). To do proper pagination you need an offset URL parameter as well, that will tell the server what is the index of the first you want to have and the limit tells how many to send. Try to challenge the API

Comment: @BencePattogato Thanks, very much !!!

Comment: `loadPersons(page: nextPageIndex)` where you are updating `nextPageIndex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The APIs are generally stateless in most cases until you want to preserve session. So you need to tell server **which page** and what will be your **page size**. Now there are various approaches playing with dynamics of page number and page size where you want to change page size in between continuous loading or you want to fix it.
 One of the approach would be sending input for **pageSize** and **pageNumber** from client side to server in first hit and then client can get response for complete url for next page with the same **pageSize**. This way your api can work on both if you want to send **pageNumber** or without it as well.